# Loading index.php from the root directory for every request in IIS

Tags: php, iis

I'm on a shared IIS host, and I honestly have no idea how I would accomplish this.  The index.php page is in the root directory of the host, and rather than creating directories for every single page, is it possible to load index.php for every single page request?

Example:

User requests http:foo.com/bar/ (the "bar" directory does not exist in the root folder)

Server serves http://foo.com/index.php whether the directory exists or not.

I'm used to Apache's method of doing this through htaccess, but I have absolutely no idea how I would accomplish this in IIS. The only workaround that I can imagine that doesn't involve htaccess is setting the 404 error page to /index.php, but this prevents GET variables from being passed through the URL.  Thanks!

Comment: You can using web.config in IIS, see this example: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to php, and I've only messed with apache, but can you redirect you 404 page to index.php?

sorry if this makes me sounds like a noob.

Comment: You can set an error page as /index.php, which works absolutely fine.  The only problem is that you can't pass GET variables to it through the URL. It sees the variables as set, but they contain no value when called.

Comment: what about setting error page to /error.php and call the header(location: '..../index.php');